# Autogenerate CMS crud forms with Laravel 4

Tags: php, forms, content-management-system, laravel, laravel-4

My company recently started working with Laravel 4. I'm now in the process of building a basic CMS. I've already found out that there are many ways to reach any goal you can think of and I'm greatly in love with composer and packagist ;) For most anything I would normally build myself I've found an existing package. Just not for this one thing:

What I'm looking for at the moment is a good way to define or generate the basic crud views for any cms controller. For example, image a list of products to be sold and each product has properties ( a few of which are 1-n or 1-1 relationships ). In this case I would either need to build a massive form view to be able to manage all these variables manually, or I would find someway to generate it. If it was just this one time, I'd simply build the form. But because there will be many more similar modules I'd like an easier and DRY method.

I've considered making a artisan generator for this purpose, wich uses the model to figure out all fields and relations. That is great for the first setup, but still requires manual work for special cases or changes afterwards.

So I thought defining the form in a multidimensional array and then using that to generate the nescesary formfields, even with support for Form::macro expressions in the view for very specific needs.

This works fine and I've got it working fairly easily but after adding many whishes ( like nesting of form items in groups etc ) it slowly became more cumbersome to manage.

I've been searching for packages or smart solutions for this problem but so far haven't found anything usable. Hence my posting of this question.

I'd love to hear your thoughts on the subject.
Thanks!

Comment: There is https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators#scaffolding for normal scaffolding, I know it's not exactly what you are after but it's a start.

Comment: I have actually used this as a starting point. But it's incomplete ( no foreign fields ) and it generates simple bootstrap 2 elements, where I have custom layouts based on BS3

Comment: Take a look at http://administrator.frozennode.com/ for an autogenerated backend.